# Unsafe url occur When Local Video path Used in IOS under <video>ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

i am giving Content-security-policy in Media-src but issue is still pending .
Please Help me to Sort this.

I am using video src not iframe 
IF I USE DOMSANITIZER it give [object object] i cant debug this issue it works on android perfectly .

```js
 fileTransfer.download(item, downloadPath).then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete1: ' + entry.toURL());
      debugger
    
      let es =this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(downloadPath)
      // window.URL.createObjectURL
      imagePath= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(es)
 
      var obj = {
                    seasonId: sid,
                    id: cid,
                    çç:  imagePath
        
                  }
                  this.offlineDataUrl.push(obj)
```

```html
<div class="video-container" *ngIf="showVideoPLayer">
                <vg-player class="home" (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)" >
                <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
                <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
                <vg-controls>
                   <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
                   <vg-playback-button ></vg-playback-button>
                   <ion-icon class="back" (click)="backward()"></ion-icon>
                   <ion-icon class="forward" (click)="forward()"></ion-icon>
                   <vg-time-display class="timeremain" vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
                   <vg-scrub-bar>
                      <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
                      <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
                   </vg-scrub-bar>
               <vg-time-display class="timeremain" vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
                   <vg-time-display class="timeremain" vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
                   <vg-mute></vg-mute>
                   <vg-volume></vg-volume>
              
                   <vg-fullscreen  (click)=checkScreen($event)></vg-fullscreen>
                </vg-controls>
                <video [vgMedia]="media" poster="../../assets/img/xxxxxxx.jpg" #media
                  id="singleVideo" preload="auto" playsinline [src]="{{this.offlineDataUrl[0].path}} " crossorigin>
                </video>
              
                </vg-player>
             </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code? This is not enough for people to help.

Comment: ok Please Wait i provide you

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have an assumption. Angular treats all URLs as untrusted by default. So you need to sanitize them like this:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('your-url');
}
```

Then you can use the URL.

Comment: In my Html under <video> it comes as [object object]

Comment: have DomSanitizer work for <video> tag ? because in my case it won't

Comment: Yes, it should work. Here a pretty good guide about the DOM sanitizer: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90?gi=493fb6b09c81

Comment: NOT WORKING FOR ME